# LG G2 "Fastboot mode started"

Tags: fastboot, lg, htc-desire-z

Hello guys I have flashed Lollipop zip via TWRP successfully (LG G2 D802) but now phone is only booting in "fastboot mode started". I have also tried to repair download mode by following xda forum but still same screen. LG logo appears and then fastboot mode started, Can anyone help me? Can I flash system, data, etc via fastboot? If yes please provide me the link. 
Thanks in advance. I am waiting eagerly for your reply.
Regards,
Ashar

Comment: You can flash from fastboot rather easily but could you link the tutorial (from XDA) that you followed? And, yeah, please do link the tutorial that you followed for TWRP.

Comment: Thanks for your response I have installed TWRP via AutoRec. I have followed "http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2477595" this tutorial. Also TWRP is working fine before this now I have no Download Mode, No recovery, only Fastboot mode. Can you please give detailed instructions on how to flash via fastboot (and links possible).

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65252/stuck-in-fastboot-help-please). Did you try the solution there?

Comment: I want to tell you that I am able to go to recovery mode. Should I flash the Rom which was working now via TWRP. Sorry for late response.

Comment: You can flash any flashable .zip (ROM) from Recovery as long as it is meant for your device. Go ahead and make backup if there is something important you don't want to lose. But, how did you succeed in getting into Recovery mode. Earlier, you had trouble getting into it. Please write an answer so that others can benefit in future. Good Luck!

Comment: OK, I have pressed all three buttons which take it into some Chinese/or like it screen. Then I press the first option (everything in Chinese or like it). It enters into fastboot mode. Then I turn off and press power on and volume up which takes me to recovery. Now please help me; I have flashed Optimus G3 Rom.zip which work perfectly before but now it shows boot certification error after successful install. Is this due to that lfg.img which I have flahed earlier by xda thread. Please help...

Comment: Anyone to help?

Comment: Make [edit] in your question and it will bump in active questions. In this way, more users will be able to see the question. At this point of time, it is buried somewhere, so no point in saying "Anyone to help?". Besides, this boot certification error seems to be only related to LG devices only, so you may to do a bit more research. // Anyhow, did you try flashing a custom Recovery as I said. Do it and boot into it directly from fastboot and tell us the result.