# LG G2 D802 (No Download Mode)

Tags: fastboot, lg, twrp

I have downloaded Lollipop for G2 D802. But when I flashed it, it shows fastboot mode started. I have followed a thread on XDA and flash `LAF.img` via fastboot but still no download mode (only fastboot).

However I found a combination from which I go to recovery and flash the previous ROM (`OptimusG3.zip`) whch was working fine. But it shows "boot certification error". After a day and a half long research I found that it was due to kernel or something error. So I flashed a custom kernel via TWRP.

Now my phone is working fine except that I have no download mode. How can I get my download mode back – although my phone is working fine (Perfect 4G, no lag etc), but to be on a safer side in future?

Link to Rom (OptimusG3.zip): http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2788077
For flashing LAF.img: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2477595

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Just for clarification: What device do you have? a) you've tagged "HTC Desire Z" and also "LG" (which already is a contradiction), b) you've tried to flash "G2 D802", c) OptimusG3 is running fine on it. No offense, but that looks a bit confusing. Am I assuming correctly your device is an [LG G3](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_g3-6294.php)? If so: which one exactly (D850/851/852/855)?

Comment: @Izzy i think the OP's device is [LG G2 D802](http://www.lg.com/in/mobile-phones/lg-G2-D802-32GB) as mentioned in the title and his [other question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111715/lg-g2-fastboot-mode-started). But as the OP mentioned 4g is working, in the tech specs section no 4G support is mentioned which is still confusing since G3 has lte support

Comment: @Lucky I think OP should say so explicitly. If it were a G2, why then did the G2 ROM fail but the G3 ROM is "working fine"? That additionally to the 4G stuff you're mentioning. Ashar might as well have multiple devices :) And after all: Whether it's a G2 or a G3, none of the two is a HTC Desire Z – I guess here we agree :)

Comment: Oh soory, I have tagged HTC Desire wrongly my device is LG G2 D802. As I said it was running a "Custom Rom i.e: Optimus G3.zip". There is full support of 4G on D802. I am saying that my device is not booting into Download Mode, while it is working fine. (Again I have D802 which have 100% LTE Support". Rom is port of G3 for G2.)

Comment: Please link those ROMs / packages and the XDA guide you're following.

Comment: I have used this thread:"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2477595%22" to flash laf.img (I think this is the problem but not sure). For Rom I have followed this link:"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2788077".

Comment: I have provided the links above...